# "For each given real number s, find a real number $t$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ so that the point on the unit circle $P(t) = P(s)$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can someone please help me decipher what this means? I understand perfectly how to find the point on a unit circle corresponding to an angle. For example, an angle of $3\pi$ correlates to $1\frac12$ rotations.

Comment: It's just asking for the canonical representative of $s\mod 2\pi$. So if $s=3\pi$, we have $t=\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it's really asking me to do is to find an angle/arc length t that is in the given interval and whose corresponding point on the unit circle is the point that corresponds with the given angle/arc length s.

Answer (score 0):

For each point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ you can find a unique $t\in [0,2\pi)$ such that
$$
(x,y) = (\cos(t),\sin(t)).
$$
This is what is meant by the point $P(t)$ on the unit circle. So, if you are given $s\in\mathbb R$, you find $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $s + 2k\pi\in [0,2\pi)$. Call this number $t$. Since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are $2\pi$-periodic, you have $P(s) = P(t)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "2pi-periodic"?